# Adding λI to the Hamiltonian has no impact?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Show that If we add λΙ in H, where I is the identical operator and $λ\in\mathbb{R}$, it won't affect any measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't affect the measurement, due to the fact, that identity operator commutes with everything. In Schroedinger picture:
$$
\langle \psi(t) | A | \psi(t) \rangle =   
\langle \psi | e^{-i (H - \lambda I) t} A e^{i (H - \lambda I) t} | \psi \rangle =  
$$
$$
= e^{-i \lambda t }\langle \psi | e^{-i H t} A e^{i H t} | \psi \rangle e^{i \lambda t} = \langle \psi | e^{-i H t} A e^{i H t} | \psi \rangle
$$
Where $A$ is any observable.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How to you justify the second equality? Am I missing some property?

Comment: @DisjointUnion exponent of scalar matrix (proportional to identity) is a scalar matrix. And in because $I$ commutes with everything, one may simply split $e^{i (H - \lambda I) t} = e^{i H t} e^{-i \lambda t} $. And the scalar matrix acts on any state, as multiplication by a number.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|\Psi \rangle$ be some state in which the system is. Then the energy expectation value is:

$$\langle \Psi|(H-\lambda I)|\Psi \rangle = \langle \Psi|H|\Psi \rangle - \lambda.$$

Note that $|\Psi \rangle$ is arbitrary so we see that this just corresponds to an overall shift of the energy. For comparing energy levels this does not matter but for energy levels it does matter.

Comment: Indeed, it is just shifting the energy origin.